# Translation mistake "Treffer durchsuchen"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, localization

There is a wrongly translated text on the german Careers start page:

[image]

> Search hits

has been translated to

> Treffer durchsuchen

which means "search for hits" (as in the activity). A more accurate translation would be something like

> Suchtreffer

or

> Treffer in der Suche

The current text might be confusing people, because it looks like something you would put on a link or button, but it is not clickable here.

Comment: Agreed, that one's off. How about something like "In Suchergebnissen"?

Comment: Yes, that might translate the meaning of the number behind it even better.

Comment: Or, even more accurate: "Angezeigt in Suchergebnissen"

Comment: Well, at least it made sense. The wrong sense, but sense nonetheless. The first two items, on the other hand, make no sense whatsoever. What the *heck* is "öffentliche Ansichten" or "Arbeitgeber-Ansichten" supposed to mean? Go grab any number of Germans off the street, ask them, I'll wait. At best you'll get "public opinions" and "employer notions", but you are more likely to hear it's just gibberish.

Comment: Well, I am German and I understood what they meant in the context, but I guess they could be improved as well. "Ansichten" is really more common to mean "opinions", maybe "Besuche" or "Profilbesuche" would be better. (as in "visits" and "profile visits")

Comment: Besuche, Views, Clicks, Hits, Profil angeschaut, Profil geklickt, wasweißich, really anything at all is better than Ansichten. That's what postcards are there for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed.

[image]

Comment: [ausgezeichnet](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ausgezeichnet "outstanding, excellent")